# Why we can't rename a pipeline without cloning in ADF?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Please answer in the form of reason and reason behind it.
What happens in behind if we rename a pipeline?
I tried to find out its answer but still, I'm unable to get the answer.

Comment: Need some more details as to what you have tried, where you have looked etc...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can change the name of pipeline here.

click Properties button, then rename it, finally publish this pipeline is ok.
[image]